# "make" or "make up" in context?

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

Tell me please if I have to use **make** or *make up* in the following context.

> To make sure you have a good understanding of how to use the present simple, I want you to **make** (**up**) a few sentences in it.

Comment: Please look up words before asking. make up is to invent. We write sentences in English, we don't make them

Answer (score 1):

The phrasal verb "**to make up**" means "*to compose in mind, to bring to existence*" (it means a lot more than that but let's stick to the context) whereas "**to make**" commonly means "*to create, build, start, do, produce, process, compose physically*".

In your case the sentences don't exist so one needs to "**make them up**".

Comment: Very clear indeed.